# AXM 27" monitor 2560x1440 native resolution

Tags: windows, resolution

I have Windows 10 Pro with the latest updates, and I have a Quadro P2000 video card. I have updated the drivers, but the system video setting is only showing me 1980✕1080 as the recommended resolution. The AXM 27" monitor has a 2560✕1440 native resolution. I have it connected with an HDMI cable.

Comment: If you are using a very old HDMI cable or adaptor it may be limited. Make sure that they support at least HDMI 1.3 or 1.4.

Comment: [HDMI 1.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_1.3) is the first version that supports 2560×1440 at 60 Hz